# orders that have more than 1 product

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

This is my database

I need to show

1) Orders that have more than 1 product

2) List of sold quantities for each product

```
ORDERS

Number_ord(PK)  Buyer   Delivery_address    Date

1               Martin  Chicago             2018-12-16
2               John    Berlin              2018-12-17
3               Martin  Chicago             2018-12-18


PRODUCTS

Number_prod Number_ord(FK)  Qty
469841      1               15
469841      2               15
999999      2               6
558585      2               45
469841      3               15
844444      3               80
```

1)I wrote something like that, but it's wrong

```
SELECT orders.Number_ord 
FROM orders 
join products USING(Number_ord) 
GROUP BY COUNT(Number_prod)>1
```

2)Here, I have a problem too

```
SELECT count(products.Number_prod),sum(products.Qty) 
FROM orders 
join products USING(Number_ord) 
GROUP BY Number_prod
```

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `HAVING` to filter based on the count.

```
SELECT orders.Number_ord, SUM(products.Qty)
FROM orders
JOIN products USING (Number_ord)
GROUP BY orders.Number_ord
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```